# Pandas Inconsistent Boolean Comparisons

Tags: python, pandas

I'm running into an issue which probably has an obvious fix. So i have a 2x2 dataframe that has lists in it. When i take the first row and compare the entire row against a specific list value i'm looking for, the boolean array that is returned is entirely False. This is incorrect since the first value of the row has the exact value i'm looking for. When I instead compare the singular value in the dataframe, I get True. How come, when doing boolean operations over the entire row, I get False instead of True for the value in the first column. Thanks in advance!

Returns False for both values in the first row.

```
In:
    static_levels = pd.DataFrame([[[58, 'Level']], [[24.4, 'Level'], [23.3, 'Level']]], ['Symbol 1', 'Symbol 2'])
    print(static_levels.loc['Symbol 1',:]==[58, 'Level'])
Out:
0    False
1    False
Name: Symbol 1, dtype: bool
```

However, the code below correctly returns True when comparing just the first value in the first row:

```
In: print(static_levels.loc['Symbol 1',0]==[58, 'Level'])
Out: True
```

Comment: `static_levels.loc['Symbol 1',0]` returns the list where `static_levels.loc['Symbol 1',:]` returns a series you could do something like `static_levels.loc['Symbol 1',:].values==pd.Series([[58, 'Level']]).values`

Comment: So its comparing the entire series to the single value? I would have assumed that it would have treated the single value on the right side of the == as a scalar and checked it versus each individual value in the series. If I alter the dataframe to only consist of the numeric values from each list, then the boolean operation properly works with a single integer scalar, without having to use .values. Don't see why it should treat it any different in the case of a list scalar value.